# Can I add custom fields to the account creation page in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I would preferably do this in the settings or control panel somewhere but if that's not possible It's not a problem. I can work with java as well. So far if've tried looking at hte custom fields but can't find a way to add htem.

ANy help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The custom fields should be there already, if the user has permissions to edit them. From that point of view: Yes, you can.

Unfortunately, during Account creation, you're typically dealing with an unauthenticated user, and if you give the unauthenticated user permission to edit those fields, they will be able to do so even later and for other user's accounts. Probably not what you want.

My suggestion is to rethink the process, e.g. enter that data later, introduce a custom registration process or modify the UI and stock registration process. In that order.